# How to share my internet connection with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, osx, raspberry-pi

I connected my Raspberry Pi, that runs Arch Linux, to my Mac with an ethernet cable using [this tutorial](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/). I set the ip of the Raspberry Pi in the `cmdline.txt` file to `192.254.0.2`. My Mac automatically got the ip `192.254.80.103`. I am able to log me in on the RPi using SSH. Here comes a diagram of the network:

[image]

Now I need an internet connection on the RPi and I want to share the WiFi connection of the Mac with the RPi. Thus I enabled the sharing of the internet connection in the settings, but then I am not able to connect to the RPi anymore.

I already found some similar questions, but they are either about Linux to Linux connections or about outdated OS X versions. I would be very grateful if someone could help me accomplishing this task.

Comment: I found [another tutorial](https://galem.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/configuring-the-raspberry-pi-to-share-a-macs-internet-connection/) which has more details on how to set the static ip of the ethernet adapter. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs rather either to Super User, or to Network Engineering.

Comment: Unless you really know you should be using 192.254.*.* as your network, don't. Use 192.168.*.* or 10.254.*.* instead.